# Reordering a list based on a boolean function in C?

Tags: c, list, sorting, linked-list

Given a list and a boolean function f, how do I reorder that list such that all elements such that f(element) == 1 are in the front (the internal order of these elements doesn't matter) and all elements that f(element) == 0 are at the end of the list (again, their internal order doesn't matter).

I tried but it got really messy, with lots of pointers. I was wondering if anyone knows of a "clean" way to do this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: And where is there the list?

Comment: Some code would be useful. If you really do have a linked-list (per your tag) then can't give you a good answer without the structure.

Comment: Wouldn't qsort work on any linked list?

Comment: qsort works on contiguous chunks of memory only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array, use qsort:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Here is a sample comparator that is compatible with qsort and uses f.

```
int comp(const void* elem1, const void* elem2) {
    int a = f(*((type*)elem1)) ? 1 : 0;
    int b = f(*((type*)elem2)) ? 1 : 0;
    return a - b;
}
```

If you have a linked list then:

```
linkedlist* sort(linkedlist* head) {
  linkedlist* newHead = NULL;
  linkedlist* newTail = NULL;
  linkedlist* backHead = NULL;
  linkedlist* backTail = NULL;

  linkedlist* currNode = head;
  while (currNode != NULL) {
    if (f(currNode)) {
      if (newHead == NULL) {
        newHead = newTail = currNode;
      } else {
        newTail.next = currNode;
        newTail = currNode;
      }
    } else {
      if (backHead == NULL) {
        backHead = backTail = currNode;
      } else {
        backTail.next = currNode;
        backTail = currNode;
      }
    }

    currNode = currNode.next;
  }

  if (currTail != NULL) {
     currTail.next = backHead;
  }
  if (backTail != NULL) {
     backTail.next = NULL;
  }
  return currHead != NULL ? currHead : backHead;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to sort chess moves based on whether they are capturing moves or not. f is a function of both the game and a given element of a list (move). Is there a way to make this compatible with the comparator?

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the first node that fails the predicate.
2. Find the next node that passes the predicate.
3. Swap the data
4. Continue until no nodes after the first fail pass the predicate.